# Form with multiple products Paypal

Tags: html, paypal

I have form which should contains multiple products with id, name and quantity of the every single product but when I send this form to Paypal Sandbox it does not show this information, only blank field to enter name, could you show how should this kind of form look like?

My form:

```
            <form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
                      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.com">
                      <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="https://mydomain.com/logo.jpg">
                      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                      <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="6543">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Name of product 1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quantity1" value="2">

                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="1111">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Name of product 2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quantity2" value="1">

                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="2343">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Name of product 3">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quantity3" value="2">

                      <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="Order ID: 1234">
                      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1000">                      
                      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
                      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://mydomain.com/">
                      <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">      
                      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN">
                      <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="OK_BuyNow_EN">
                      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but6.gif" name="submit" alt="Pay with PayPal" title="Pay with PayPal">
            </form>
```

Also, how can I get information form Paypal that payment was successful or not?

Answer (score 0):

I only know this in vb.net and asp.net hopefully you can convert this to whatever language you need but I will post anyways with the chance that it will help you out. use something like this in an On_click event for your paypal button.

This is my sql query which searches through to get the product that I want since I have 1,000's of products this allows me to pull just one and assign all the rest of the values needed to be sent to paypal

```
 Dim itemName As String

    Conn.Open()
    sql4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", url)
    sql4.CommandText = "Select [Table] From SubCategory WHERE Category = @Category OR Type = @Category"
    sql4Str = sql4.ExecuteScalar.ToString

    sql3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order", testIndex)
    sql3.CommandText = ("Select * From " + sql4Str + " WHERE Order# = @Order")
    Dim cost As String
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String       
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sql3.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read()
        Str = reader.GetOrdinal("Category")
        If reader.IsDBNull(Str) Then
            Str = reader("Type")

        ElseIf Not reader.IsDBNull(Str) Then
            Str = reader("Category")
        End If
        cost = reader("Price")
        str2 = reader("Order#")

        itemName = Str
    End While
```

Now that itemName has been assigned to whatever the dynamic value of ("Category") was I can just pass the value of itemName to paypal along with any of the other values that you want to use.

```
Dim Item As String = "Test"
Dim price As String = cost
Dim business As String = "YourEmail@email.com"
Dim itemNumber As String = str2
Dim itemAmount As String = price
Dim currencyCode As String = "USD"
Dim addItem As Integer = 1

Dim ppHref As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
ppHref.Append("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart")
ppHref.Append("&business=" + business)
ppHref.Append("&item_name=" + itemName)
ppHref.Append("&item_number=" + itemNumber)
ppHref.Append("&amount=" + itemAmount)
ppHref.Append("&currency_code=" + currencyCode)
ppHref.Append("&tax_rate=4")
ppHref.Append("&add=" + addItem.ToString("#0"))
Response.Redirect(ppHref.ToString(), True)
Dim ReturnQaunity As String = itemAmount
GetRouteUrl("/v1/payments/orders/<Order-Id>")
```

and your paypal button something like this in your markup

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AddToCartBtn" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
   ImageUrl="~/Pictures/ShoppingCart.png"                                          
  OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" />
```

Comment: I see that you handle it with link. This code handle also multiple products at one time? For single product you put "item_name=" how this looks for second product "item_name_2=" ?

Comment: Yes I have hundreds of products that are loaded into this dynamically. I will edit my answer above in a little bit but I basically run a sql query for whatever item was selected and then set item_Name equal to that value so that it will dynamically load them. You just need to set whatever your possible products are equal to the variables listed above.

Comment: I would maybe use something like a for loop or if statements to figure out which product was selected that you want to send to paypal and then set that value = Item_name, This way all your products will be set to the Item_name variable,  so it will just depend on either your if statement or for loop (however you want to distinguish which product was selected) as to which one gets sent to paypal.

Comment: OK, so the problem is not to get all data but what kind of data I need? I've solve the problem, in my form I didn't had "amount_" for single product, because I thought that I could sand to paypal only the name, number and quantity of the single product and amount of all products. Now I have problem with shipping costs of total order. I send to paypal shipping `<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="20.00">` but Paypal seems to not get it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not positive about the shipping, I actually for some reason haven't done anything with that yet in the site i'm developing. I'm pretty sure that in your paypal account online (actually log into their website), somewhere in your developer settings you can add flat rate shipping. If you strictly want $20 shipping you could just do it there.